# Executing and viewing current bash command on command line

Tags: command-line, bash

Executing and viewing bash command using the command line

I have a line of code that batch converts images but it doesn't show what image it's current operating on.  Is there a way I can insert `echo` to show the command it's currently executing?

```
for i in *.jpg; do convert $i -filter Lanczos -resize 50% converted_$i.jpeg; done;


Example:
After each line it I would like it to show the file it's converting
img1.jpeg converted
img2.jpeg converted
```

**PS:  I'm looking to run this from the command line.  I don't want to create a separate file and run that**.

Comment: The `convert` command has `-verbose` flag. Try it. Also for more information about the command use `man convert`.

Comment: `for i in *.jpg; do convert $i -filter Lanczos -resize 50% converted_$i.jpeg; echo "$i" converted; done`

Comment: @Raffa  Thanks nice and simple... :-)

Comment: @Raffa, that is the answer so do not hesitate to post as one.

Comment: @vanadium done that :-)

Comment: And rather extensively so ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Background

In **bash** a `for` loop is used to assign a range(*i.e. a list of items*) within which a command(*or a group of commands*) is executed ... The range(*AKA condition*) is set within the first part of the `for` loop i.e. the part before the `do`(*command grouping construct*) e.g. `for i in 1 2 3`(*will work in the range of 1-3 or on the elements in the list 1,2 and 3*) ... The command(*or the group of commands*) is defined between the `do` and `done` command grouping constructs(*these can be substituted **in case of a `for` loop only** with `{` and `}` in place of `do` and `done` respectively*) AKA the body of the `for` loop.

When writing a `for` loop, every command/part of the loop(*except the command grouping constructs*) needs to terminate either with a new line or a semicolon e.g.:

```bash
for i in 1 2 3
    do
    echo "$i"
    done
```

or

```bash
for i in 1 2 3
    do echo "$i"
    done
```

or

```bash
for i in 1 2 3; do echo "$i"
    done
```

or

```bash
for i in 1 2 3; do echo "$i"; done
```

or with `{ ... }` instead of `do ... done` command grouping constructs:

```bash
for i in 1 2 3; { echo "$i"; }
```

**Notice** that the usage of the undocumented `{ ... }` command grouping constructs instead of the documented `do ... done` in a `for` loop in bash is not common(*due to lack of proper documentation*) and not advised(*due to compatibility reasons and there is no guarantee it will still work in future versions of bash*) ... I just included it to further illustrate the concept of the command grouping constructs.

**Furthermore**, in a `for` loop, if the range(*i.e. `in WORDS ...` e.g. `in 1 2 3`*) is not present, then `in "$@"`(*i.e. the list of positional parameters*) is assumed e.g.:

```bash
set -- 1 2 3; for i; do echo "$i"; done
```

#### Answer to your question

> Is there a way I can insert `echo` to show the command it's currently
> executing?

Yes, you can do `for ...; do command1; command2; command3; done` like so:

```bash
for i in *.jpg; do echo "converting $i"; convert "$i" -filter Lanczos -resize 50% converted_$i.jpeg; [ "$?" -eq 0 ] && echo "$i converted"; done
```

**Notice** I added `[ "$?" -eq 0 ] && echo "$i converted"` which will check the exit status code of the previous command and `echo "$i converted"` will only be executed if the exit status code of the previous command was `0`(*i.e. success*) which should mean that the image was successfully converted.

Comment: Interestingly, the `for …; { … }` syntax seems to work in `ksh` and `zsh` — but not in `ash` or `dash` (nor `csh` or `tcsh`, though that's no surprise).

Comment: +1 for `{ ... }` I didn't know that!