# Remove all symlinks in a folder

Tags: symbolic-link

How do I remove all symlinks in a folder (dozens of them) at once? It's not practical to insert every single one of them by hand when using unlink or rm.

Comment: What do you mean by "folder"? Are you just talking about what Linux calls directories, or do you have some other usage in mind?

Answer (score 34):

You can use the `find`-command to do that:

```
find /path/to/directory -maxdepth 1 -type l -delete
```

To be on the safe side, check first without the `-delete`-option:

```
find /path/to/directory -maxdepth 1 -type l
```

`-maxdepth 1` ensures that `find` will look only in `/path/to/directory` but not in it's subfolders for symlinks. Feel free to take a look at `man find`.

Comment: Thanks. "find /path/to/directory -maxdepth 1 -type l -delete" did the trick.

Answer (score 14):

List the links in the current directory alias folder and **check** that you really want to remove them,

```
find -type l -ls                  # search also in subdirectories

find -maxdepth 1 -type l -ls      # search only in the directory itself
```

If things look good, and you want to **delete** these links, run

```
find -type l -delete              # delete also in subdirectories

find -maxdepth 1 -type l -delete  # delete only in the directory itself
```

If you want to **delete interactively**, you can use the following command line (this is safer)

```
find -type l -exec rm -i {} +              # delete also in subdirectories

find -maxdepth 1 -type l -exec rm -i {} +  # delete only in the directory itself
```

Comment: With the first interactive option, you may also want to use `-depth` to ensure depth-first traversal - that is, that it asks about `root/symlink1/symlink2` before `root/symlink1`.

Comment: @minnmass: But `find` won't follow symlinks by default, so it won't find `root/symlink1/symlink2` - it'll find `root/symlink1`, but not try to look for things under it (even if it's a link to a directory).

Comment: @psmears: derp; I'm too used to treating symlinks to directories as just directories, and the abstraction broke. ... never mind.

Comment: Was going to comment exactly this but not quite as complete... beat me to it 

Comment: @minnmass 'find' by default won't search directories that are symlinks to outside the root dir. You can use -L to tell it to dereference symlinks which iirc works for directories.

Answer (score 10):

### For users of the [Z shell](https://zsh.org/), `rm *(@)` will achieve this.

Zsh supports [glob qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) that limit the type of files a glob (such as `*`) applies to, for example `(/)` for directories, `(x)` for executable files, `(L0)` for empty files, and `(@)` for symlinks.

For symlinks:

```
% ll
lrwxrwxrwx 1 test test 3 Aug  8 15:51 bar -> foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 test test 0 Aug  8 15:51 baz
-rw-r--r-- 1 test test 0 Aug  8 15:52 foo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 test test 4 Aug  8 15:51 qux -> /etc/ 

% rm *(@)                                                                         
removed 'bar'
removed 'qux'

% ll                                                                              
-rw-r--r-- 1 test test 0 Aug  8 15:51 baz
-rw-r--r-- 1 test test 0 Aug  8 15:52 foo
```

Comment: Nice :-) … probably a dry-run with `echo` first before using `rm` might be a good idea to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 7):

In **bash**(*and most shells*) … The builtin command [`test`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/test.1.html) and its variant `[` has an option `-h`(*or `-L` if it’s easier to remember*) that will return success(*`exit 0`*) for a file if it exists and is a symbolic link … So it can be used in a shell loop like so:

```bash
for f in *
    do
    if [ -h "$f" ]
        then 
        echo rm -- "$f"
    fi
done
```

or a one liner like so:

```bash
for f in *; do if [ -h "$f" ]; then echo rm -- "$f"; fi done
```

or even more compact(*bash specific … although reported to be working in [zsh and ksh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419152/executing-and-viewing-current-bash-command-on-command-line/1419265#comment2476464_1419265) as well*) like so:

```bash
for f in *; { [ -h "$f" ] && echo rm -- "$f"; }
```

**Notice:**

`echo` is there for a dry-run ... When satisfied with the output, remove `echo` to delete the links.

Comment: A bit more compact: `[ -h "$f" ] && rm -- "$f"`

Comment: @PabloBianchi Yep, … only a bit though :-) … But, can be compacted more if the command grouping constructs `{}` are used with the `for` loop … https://askubuntu.com/a/1419265