# How do I .zip multiple files and retain their file names. EX file1.file file2.file -> file1.zip file2.zip

Tags: zip, gzip

As the title suggests I need to .zip multiple files (thousands) in a folder and have each file zipped into their own archive with the original file name as the .zip filename.

If I try to do this with gzip, it is simple:

```
   $gzip *.fileextension
```

and it will .gz each file, delete the original and rename itself to the original filename

Example
Input:
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

Output:
file1.gz
file2.gz
file3.gz

HOW DO I DO THIS WITH .ZIP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a small bash shellscript `zipsep`,

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "$@"
do
 zip "$i".zip "$i"
done
```

Make it executable,

```
chmod +x zipsep
```

Move it to a directory in PATH,

```
sudo mv zipsep /usr/local/bin
```

Now you can use `zipsep` to zip each file separately, for example

```
zipsep *.txt
```

---

If you want to remove the original files, you can do that separately afterwards in the example above by

```
rm *.txt
```

or interactively if only a few files (safer)

```
rm -i *.txt
```

It is also possible to put the removal into the shellscript, but I would prefer to do it separately.

---

Edit: If there will be no problem with files with the same name with different extensions for example `file1.txt` and `file1.doc` and `file2.pdf`, you can use a bash parameter substitution to remove the original extension from the zip file name. See `man bash` and search for 'Parameter Expansion' and `${parameter%word}` 'Remove matching suffix pattern'.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "$@"
do
 zip "${i%.*}".zip "$i"
done
```

If you already created zip files without removing the original extension, you can use the following command to check, that it works as intended 'dry run',

```
rename -n 's/\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\././' *.zip
```

and then remove the option `-n` to do it,

```
rename 's/\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\././' *.zip
```

With this method you will avoid overwriting if there were original files with the same name and different extensions. At least my version of `rename` will refuse to overwrite, 'perl rename': See `man rename`:

> The original "rename" did not check for the existence of target
> filenames, so had to be used with care.  I hope I've fixed that (Robin
> Barker).

Comment: +1! I was doing aliases in `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases` and didn't know you can add your shellscripts to that location ~ however when should be advisable to no put your files there, and if is there any other special location maybe in `/usr/`. Or just create your own folder in `~/shellscripts` and add it to `$PATH`

Comment: `zipsep` is a tongue twister :-) … Probably extra info, but that for loop might work without the `in "$@"` part … it’s the default behavior … https://askubuntu.com/a/1419265

Comment: @SatoshiNakamoto, the old style is to create `~/bin` and put your own shellscripts and other executables there, and after reboot `~/bin` will be in PATH. Then only you have access to them. If you want general access to your own shellscripts and other executables, put them in `/usr/local/bin`. There is also `/usr/local/sbin` for executables that need sudo.

Comment: Thanks for that information @Raffa :-)

Comment: @sudodus thanks for the info!! Yes I prefer all the old school way of things

Comment: Thank you. This works! However now each file is: file1.txt.zip  how do I remove the .txt part?

Comment: I thought that is best to keep the extensions, because there might be files with the same name with different extensions for example `file1.txt` and `file1.doc` and `file2.pdf`. If this is never the case, you can use a bash parameter substitution, that I will append to the answer.