# How to find all images with a certain pixel size using command line and move them to new folder

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to find all photos that are not equal to a 256 pixels in height and length and move them to a new folder. So far I was able to write up the following code in the terminal that outputs in to the terminal a list of all the photos that math the criteria:

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f | xargs -I{} identify -format '%w %h %i' {} | awk '$1!=256 || $2!=256'
```

Now I wish to move all of these photos to a new folder. I tried the following:

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f | xargs -I{} identify -format '%w %h %i' {} | awk '$1<300 || $2<300' -exec mv "{}" ~/path_to_location/ \;
```

I am getting an error that there is

> no such file or directory named exec

and also:

> xargs identidy: terminated by signal 13

Would love your help
Thanks

Comment: This would be no surprise. The find command ends after the first pipe symbol |. Your `-exec` is seen as an argument to your `awk` command, and of course, `awk` does not know what to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can do it in a `for` loop like so:

```bash
for f in *.jpg
do 
     if [ -f "$f" ] # Check if it is a file
     then
        w=$(identify -format '%w' "$f") # Get width
        h=$(identify -format '%h' "$f") # Get hight
        [[ "$w" -lt 300 || "$h" -lt 300 ]] && # Check if width or hight are less than 300
        echo mv -- "$f" ~/path_to_location/ # Move the file ... "echo" is for simulation only ... remove "echo" when satisfied with the output to move files.
    fi
done
```

Related references:

- [`for` loop](https://askubuntu.com/a/1419265/968501).
- [Test Constructs](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html).
- [File test operators](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html).
- [Comparison Operators](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're aiming for is something like

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f -exec identify -format '%w %h %i\n' {} + | 
    awk '($1 != 256 || $2 != 256) {print $3}' | xargs -I{} echo mv -n -- {} path/to/newdir/
```

(`echo` added for dry-running the command first). However, there's an obvious problem that awk's `{print $3}` will break if the filename `%i` contains whitespace. If there's another character that you can guarantee not to be present in `%i`, you could change the format to use that, for example `-format '%w:%h:%i\n'` and then modify the awk field separator accordingly i.e.

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f -exec identify -format '%w:%h:%i\n' {} + | 
  awk -F':' '($1 != 256 || $2 != 256) {print $3}' | xargs -I{} echo mv -n -- {} path/to/newdir/
```

For filenames containing whitespace but **not** newlines you could use the following bash shell construct

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f -exec identify -format '%w %h %i\n' {} + | 
  while read -r w h i; do 
    ((w != 256 || h != 256)) && echo mv -n -- "$i" path/to/newdir/ 
  done
```

which gets around the problem of word-splitting because bash's `read` slurps everything after the first two IFS-separated fields into variable `i`.

To make it handle **any** whitespace, including newlines, you'd need to set the delimiter to the null character `\0` in place of `\n` - unfortunately ImageMagick does not appear to support that. See [ImageMagick: Percent Escape Handling](https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php).