# Renaming folders and removing all characters after '(' in linux

Tags: rename

I have folders with album year and a bunch of text I don't care about and want removed/renamed. Here is what I was trying for the below files:

`Calvin Harris - This Is What You Came For (2016) [MP3-320]`

```
rename 's/(*//g' *
```

I'm getting the below error:

```
Unterminated '(*...' construct in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(* <-- HERE / at line 1, in: s/(*//g
```

I know I must be having issues with special characters. How can I rename everything after the '(' character so it would look something like this:

`Calvin Harris - This Is What You Came For`

Answer (score 2):

With [shell parameter expansion in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and [`mv`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/mv.1.html) in a [`for ...`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1419265) loop:

```bash
for f in */; do [ -d "${f/ (*/}" ] || echo mv -nv -- "$f" "${f/ (*/}"; done
```

... where `*/` will only expand to directories (***not** files*) and `[ -d "${f/ (*/}" ] ||` will prevent moving into other directories which name matches the target new name if they exist and it will also prevent `mv` trying to move directories into sub-directories under themselves and thus forcing a renaming action only.

**Notice** `echo` is for a safe dry-run, and you need to remove it when satisfied with the output for actual renaming to happen ... Please, see demonstration below:

```
$ ls
'Calvin Harris - This Is What You Came For (2016) [MP3-320]'
$
$ for f in */; do [ -d "${f/ (*/}" ] || mv -nv -- "$f" "${f/ (*/}"; done
renamed 'Calvin Harris - This Is What You Came For (2016) [MP3-320]' -> 'Calvin Harris - This Is What You Came For'
$
$ ls
'Calvin Harris - This Is What You Came For'
```

Answer (score 1):

To force a special character to be treated as a literal character in regex, you can escape it `\(` or place it inside a [bracket expression](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) `[(]`.

However, `\(*` would match a sequence of zero or more `(` characters. What you seem to want is to match a single `(` *followed by* zero or more *arbitrary* characters, which would be `\(.*` or `[(].*`. If you also want to remove the leading space character, then it would be  `\(.*`. So

```
$ rename -n 's/ \(.*//' -- *
rename(Calvin Harris - This Is What You Came For (2016) [MP3-320], Calvin Harris - This Is What You Came For)
```

If you were trying to rename *files* then bear in mind this would also remove any filename extension. So instead, you might want to match zero or more non-`]` characters followed by `\]` either

```
rename -n 's/ \([^]]*\]//' -- *
```

or (perhaps more aesthetically pleasing)

```
rename -n 's/ [(][^]]*[]]//' -- *
```

*Note that the `g` global replacement flag is not necessary here, since you are making only a single replacement per file.*

Comment: @KyloRen sorry I should have mentioned the `-n` is for testing - remove it when you're happy with the actions proposed